# How do I set it such that DVDs and CDs autorun?

Tags: 12.10, dvd, cd, autorun

As per title, I'd like to know how in 12.10 you set it such that DVDs and CDs autorun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open up "System Settings" from the Dash.
2. In the "System" category (at the bottom), click on the "Details" button.
3. Select "Removable Media" in the list on the left.  From here you can configure what happens when various kinds of removable media are inserted.  For example, you can have Rhythmbox start when you insert a music CD.